# Running feh as slideshow and speak captions each img

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, feh

So I am using the image viewer program feh to create a slideshow of images on an Rpi and display them on a touchscreen as a digital picture frame. I also would like to have the Rpi speak the captions that is associated with each image but am having difficulty with this part of the process.

I have feh running the slideshow and has the captions displayed on each image just as feh describes on doing it with using the -K option with the caption/ path in the images folder. The way I was trying to do it was getting the captions from the sub processes python lib and feeding that into py speech lib but the captions are not associated with the specific images in their meta data I am not sure on how to go about this now. I can edit this later and add the code and scripts I am using I wrote this on my phone initially.

I have finally gotten the metadata from the images but the captions are not there I am stuck on what to do at this point. My thoughts were to somehow add the captions to the meta but do not think this is a workable option

Comment: Interesting question... please add 3 images and their captions (however you have them stored) and show your [mcve].